# error - metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Got this error:

> "Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

In code I know that theres a new way for downloadURL in `Firebase 5.0.0` but I don't know how to implement it in my code...

```
        if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2) {

        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString

        let metadata = StorageMetadata()

        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).putData(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("did not upload img")
            } else {

                print("uploaded")

                let downloadURL = metadata?<error_appears>.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                if let url = downloadURL {

                    self.setUser(img: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now you need to do a separate call to [get the Download URL using the StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#downloadurlcompletion) after you finish uploading.

Comment: Change `let metadata = StorageMetadata()` to `let metadataRef = StorageMetadata()` because there is 2 object with same name.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni done that, the error still appears...

Comment: Check original question link.

Comment: Yeah I've already checked it but how to I make this changes in my code? Could you help me rewriting my code?

Comment: @JamesPoag and how am I doing this??

Comment: I would appreciate any help